# MySQL newbie: Query to find the name of each employee whose salary exceeds the average salary of all employees in his or her department

Tags: mysql, average

Print the name of each employee whose salary exceeds the average salary of all employees in 
his or her department.

- `emp (eid: integer, ename: string, age: integer, salary: real)`
- `works (eid: integer, did: integer, pct_time: integer)`
- `dept (did: integer, dname: string, budget: real, managerid: integer)`

This is what I have:

```
SELECT ename FROM emp
WHERE salary > all (
  SELECT AVG(salary) FROM dept, works
  WHERE emp.eid = works.eid AND works.did = dept.did)
```

The problem is that I seem to be getting the names of people who have a salary greater than than the average for EVERY worker. I'm thinking I don't need a link to the department table, but when I tried editing the string above, I still get the same result.

Comment: The subquery needs another join to `emp` through another copy of works: `select avg(emp2.salary) from emp as emp2 inner join works2 on emp2.eid = works2.eid inner join works on works2.did = works.did where works.eid = emp.eid`. There might be another problem caused by the fact that an employee works part time in few departments; in this case average will be calculated across all his/her departments.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach using a subquery for the average is sound, but you need to group the subquery by department. Then you can join to the subquery by:

- Department ID's are equal (equijoin), *and*
- Employee salary is greater than than the average departmental salary (non-equijoin)

Here's the query...

```
SELECT emp.ename, dept.dname, emp.salary, DeptAvg.AvgSal
FROM emp
INNER JOIN works ON emp.eid = works.eid
INNER JOIN dept ON works.did = dept.did
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT works.did, AVG(emp.salary) AS AvgSal
    FROM emp
    INNER JOIN works ON emp.eid = works.eid
    GROUP BY works.did) DeptAvg
  ON DeptAvg.did = works.did AND emp.salary > DeptAvg.AvgSal
```

This query shows employee name, department name, employee salary and average departmental salary. I did that so you can see the numbers and test it. You can remove any of the columns and the query should still work.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. We haven't covered inner joins in class yet, so I'll have to read ahead and familiarize myself. Not sure if there is another way to do the problem with more "basic" functions. Once again, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome @AndrewP. You already know inner joins. You have one in your original query: `FROM dept, works WHERE ... works.did = dept.did` lists two tables and how to join them, specifically where the `did` values are equal. I just used a different join syntax: instead of `FROM dept, works WHERE works.did=dept.did` you can say `FROM dept INNER JOIN works ON works.did=dept.did`. Same thing. You should use the syntax your professor uses, at least for the duration of your class :)

Comment: The department name was never asked for so you can leave that column and table out altogether. Otherwise, this is exactly how it should be done!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT emp.ename,dept.dname,emp.salary,avg(emp.salary) as DeptAvgSalary
FROM emp 
INNER JOIN works ON emp.eid = works.eid
INNER JOIN dept ON works.did = dept.did
group by dept.did 
having emp.salary>DeptAvgSalary
```